# FONT - Can't find a font used in psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typefaces

After a lot of search looking for this **font** it seems that there is no trace for it in the web.

this is the type-face UPPERCASE->

[image]
lowercase

[image]

in the psd the font name is ALTO.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.. You have the PSD where the font is used, is it a raster image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, ALTO:
https://ourtype.com/#/try/pro-fonts/alto/

The site uses flash though.

Answer (score 1):

The font from your image seems to be:
https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/borutta/vitali

with extra bold. Also you can use alot of online font matchers like: 
https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator

Else you can use adobe photoshop cs6 feature of 'Match font' as following:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/match-font-image.html

Comment: thanks, but the lowercase don't match the font i'm looking for

Comment: you didnt provide the lowercase image.